# My new gecko is fighting my old one!

Tags: behavior, reptiles, leopard-geckos

I got a leopard gecko about 3 weeks ago and I thought it needed a friend, so today I got another and put it in the terrarium. They are both pretty young. The new one went into the hide my old one was in, and he started fighting my new one! What do I do? They are too young to figure out if they are male or female. The guy at PetSmart said it was fine to put them together but I don't know what to do.

Comment: How big is the terrarium?

Comment: "Leopard Geckos can be housed in groups of multiple females but always only one male as Leopard Gecko males are territorial and will often fight to the death for dominance." https://thehsi.org/2014/12/19/leopard-gecko-care/  Reading this, I personally wouldn't attempt putting them together until you're sure of their gender.

Answer (score 2):

Geckos prefer to be alone. If you are housing them together, it is best to have only females, although even they can be aggressive, or it can be a sign they are stressed or they feel threatened by each other. I hope this helps.